# Extreme Point of Absolute Value Function

Tags: real-analysis, maxima-minima

How many extreme points of function $f: \mathbb{R} \mapsto \mathbb{R}, f(x) = |x^4 - 4x^3|$?

I have looked at materials about how to evaluate the extreme points of a function, but unfortunately, there are no literatures I find that explain about the function of absolute value like this problem. I tried to draw the graph by using app, and it looks like there are 2 extreme points, one is $x =0$. But, how can we find it precisely without looking at the graph?  Thanks for your help

Comment: Looking at the graph is the right place to start, to guess the answer. The graph should also show you the intervals where the function without the absolute values is positive and where it's negative. On those intervals you can use what you remember from calculus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We know that $|y-a|=\begin{cases}y-a\qquad y\geq a\\-(y-a)\qquad y<a\end{cases}$. So we just have to apply this to the function $f$ as such: $$f(x)=|x^4-4x^3|=|x|^3|x-4|=\begin{cases}x^3(x-4)\qquad x<0\\-x^3(x-4)\qquad 0\leq x< 4\\x^3(x-4)\qquad x\geq 4\end{cases}$$
Note: the first case ($x<0$) gives $|x|=-x$ and $|x-4|=-(x-4)$, so the two negatives cancel out. The second case ($0\leq x<4$) gives $|x|=x$ and $|x-4|=-(x-4)$, so we get a negative sign. And the third case ($x\geq 4$) gives $|x|=x$ and $|x-4|=x-4$, so no negative signs.

Comment: I found that the extreme points is at $x = 0$ and $x = 3$, and it matches with the graph. :)

Comment: Yes those are critical points, but there is another point ($x=4$) for which the derivative does not exist, and this point may also be of interest.

Comment: Oh you are right. Then how do we know that $x = 4$ also be the critical points?

Comment: If you want to be rigorous: for the "end points" (i.e. the points where the function is cut up: $x=0,4$) one should look at the derivative via the definition. If you just look at the graph though, then it is easy to see that $f$ has a "sharp point" at $x=4$, which indicates the derivative does not exist at this point.

Comment: For instance, using the definition of the derivative at $x=4$, we examine the right and left sided limits: $$\lim_{h\to 0^+}\frac{(4+h)^3(4+h-4)-0}{h}=4^3$$but $$\lim_{h\to 0^-}\frac{-(4+h)^3(4+h-4)-0}{h}=-4^3$$